# Crop Image Based Upon CNN Model Predicted Values for License Plates

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, conv-neural-network

I have developed a DNN Model that predicts the placements of license plates. I then want to take the predicted rectangle and crop the image based upon its placement in the image.

Current Error:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Current Code:

```
import cv2 
import imutils
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread("licensed_car109.jpeg",cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) / 255, dsize=(WIDTH, HEIGHT))

y_hat = model.predict(img.reshape(1, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3)).reshape(-1) * WIDTH

xt, yt = y_hat[0], y_hat[1]
xb, yb = y_hat[2], y_hat[3]

img = cv2.cvtColor(img.astype(np.float32), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
image = cv2.rectangle(img, (xt, yt), (xb, yb), (0, 0, 255), 1)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()

Cropped = img[x:(xt, xb), y:(yt, yb)]
```

[image: code]

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just do this `Cropped = img[xt:xb, yt:yb] `you do not need the x and y. The error is because indexes can only be ints and your second value is a tuple.

Comment: @DwightFoster unfortunately i still get the same error:( would you like to see the shape of the image?

Comment: No actually I missed that the values are floats. That is why it doesn't work. To fix this just do this `int(xt)` for all of the points. Sorry for not seeing this before.

Comment: @DwightFoster i have tried that before, when i do that because the values of the box are in float along with them being 0.0000012 or something like that, when i do int they are changed to 0. so for XT its always 0

Comment: an an example y_hat = array([5.9818709e-21, 4.3233523e-08, 2.2400000e+02, 2.2396625e+02],
      dtype=float32)

Comment: xt = 5.9818709e-21 so changing to int doesnt help :(

Comment: It may be because the model values are in a range from `[0,1]` Try and multiply each point by 255 then convert it to an int.